# What does it mean 'limited to Hive table data' in Apache Sentry reference?

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

Here https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/sentry_intro.html
we can read that

> Apache Sentry Overview Apache Sentry is a granular, role-based
>   authorization module for Hadoop. Sentry provides the ability to
>   control and enforce precise levels of privileges on data for
>   authenticated users and applications on a Hadoop cluster. Sentry
>   currently works out of the box with Apache Hive, Hive
>   Metastore/HCatalog, Apache Solr, Impala, and **HDFS (limited to Hive
>   table data)**.

What does it mean exactly that **HDFS is limited to Hive table data**?

Does it mean that I can't set privileges access for users  to particular paths on HDFS?

For example, 
I would like to set read access for `user_A` to path `/my_test1`

and write/read access for `user_B` to path `/my_test1` and path `/my_test2`.

Is it possible with `Apache Sentry`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sentry controls do not replace HDFS ACLs. The synchronization between Sentry permissions and HDFS ACLs is one-way; that is, the Sentry plugin on the NameNode will apply Sentry permissions along with HDFS ACLs, so that HDFS enforces access to Hive table data according to Sentry's configuration, even when being accessed with other tools. Thus, HDFS access control is a means to enforcement of policies defined in Sentry in such a case.

Enforcement of arbitrary file access in HDFS should still be done via HDFS ACLs.

Comment: Ok, ok everything you have written is clear for me. Let's consider two cases (in order to clarify your answer). We have to paths on HDFS: `(1) /some_data_being_part_of_some_hive_table` and `(2)  /some_data_which_have_nothing_in_common_with_hive_and_another_stuff` (they are uploaded with HDFS client (dfs -put)).  And now, lets suppose that we have set sync between HDFS ACLs and Sentry priviliages. What is going to happen in case of reading paths `(1)` and what in case of reading path `(2)`. In case of path `(2)` will it hit to Sentry Server? In case path `(1)` how effective ACLs will be set?

Comment: Do we know an answer for this? Even I had the same question